# workbench connection to ubuntu with fish shell

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-workbench, fish

I am connecting to a ubuntu server through mysql-workbench, 
when I want to view option file, I am getting one error

> LC_AL=C cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf  fish: Unknown command “LC_AL”  Did you mean set $LC_ALL C”? For information on assigning values to variables, see the help section on the set command by ...

I was wondering how the LC_ALL is not available, I spent a lot of time and tried `locale` options until I understand one of my colleague installed fish shell on the system.

The command that workbench is trying to run is becoming invalid since variables in fish need to start with `env` .

If I type `bash` in fish and then type the command that workbench is trying to run, then everything is fine

I tried to change login behavior of workbench but couldn't find any thing in their website about the configuration file.

the only configurable part look like in workbench is mysql.profiles's xml that has nothing useful about this.

Do I have any solution other than disable fish as default shell?

Comment: The error message looks strange, but are you trying to execute a shell script with `fish`? `fish` is not even remotely POSIX-compliant. While it may make a fine interactive shell, it cannot be used as a replacement for `/bin/sh` the way `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` (to name a few) can.

Comment: It looks like something may have been cut off. What is the actual command that you are running?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish @chepner: the command that workbench trying to run is `LC_AL cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf` that is correct bash command, but it's not suitable with fish, i am looking for a solution to make workbench, run `bash` command before it

Comment: Why is it written `LC_AL cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and not `LC_ALL`?

Comment: @A.L It's `LC_AL=C cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf `, as I said problem is the fish require something like this `env LC_ALL=C cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: I still don't understand why you wrote `LC_AL` instead of `LC_ALL`. Is this directive important? If you don't use it does the command work? DO you have a problem with the characters encoding?

Comment: post the output of `locale` command.